# make www.mydomain.com/[USER]/ in buddypress

Tags: wordpress, path, buddypress

Simple as that, that's excactly what I want to do in my buddypress:

www.mydomain.com/[USER]/ 
so as it will direct to user's public profiles.

I have found this link but wasn't helpful to me
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-theme-my-login-username-in-permalink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easier way:

Put profiles in the root — http://example.org/username/

```
define ( 'BP_ENABLE_ROOT_PROFILES', true );
```

This goes in your wp-content/plugins/bp-custom.php file 
If you don't have such a file, create one.

More info:
http://codex.buddypress.org/extending-buddypress/changing-internal-configuration-settings/

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to have friendly URLs?  Your question is a bit too general, you may want to rephrase it.  But if it is what I think it is do this:

1. In admin, go to `Settings -> Permalinks`
2. Choose any of the formats
3. Modify or create your .htaccess file as it tells you to at the bottom of the page
4. Get [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/edit-author-slug/) [OPTIONAL STEP]
5. Install it [OPTIONAL STEP]
6. Go to `Settings -> Edit author slug` [OPTIONAL STEP]
7. Create the slug you want for your authors [OPTIONAL STEP]
8. Go to `Users` in the admin
9. Click `edit` on any of the users
10. Go all the way to the bottom where it says "Edit Author Slug"
11. Choose the format you want

That should do it.